# .NET mshtml: How to pass a BSTR SAFEARRAY?

Tags: .net, com, interop, mshtml

The class mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass in Microsoft.mshtml.dll assembly has a method:

```
public virtual void write(params object[] psarray);
```

Avoiding the real question for a moment, what code would you use to call **write()**? Would you use:

```
String html = "<html><body>Hello, world!</body></html>";
mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass doc;
...
doc.write(html);
```

or would you use:

```
String html = "<html><body>Hello, world!</body></html>";
mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass doc;
...
object[] params = new Object[1];
params[0] = html;
doc.write(params);
```

Because both of those throw an exception. (Type mismatch. 0x80020005)

The **HTMLDocumentClass.write** method actually comes from [IHTMLDocument2 interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752639(VS.85).aspx), which is documented as:

> IHTMLDocument2::write Method
>
> Writes one or more HTML expressions to a
>   document in the specified window.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> HRESULT write(
>    SAFEARRAY *psarray
> );
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> psarray
>
> ```
>    [in] A **BSTR** that specifies the text and HTML tags to write.
> ```

So in reality the write method needs a pointer to a SAFEARRAY, even though Microsoft's **Microsoft.mshtml** interop assembly define the **write** method as taking a regular array:

```
public virtual void write(params object[] psarray);
```

Ignoring the mshtml interop declaration, i have to construct a **SAFEARRAY** object (verses an object array), fill it with a BSTR string (verses a String), and stuff it into a parameter that must be an object array.

---

Note: i'm unsure of the meaning of the **params** keyword. It is used to indicate a variable number of parameters.

Does that mean that it can take multiple array parameters?

```
object[] array1 = new Object[1];
array1 [0] = alpha;
object[] array2 = new Object[1];
array2 [0] = bravo;
object[] array3 = new Object[1];
array3 [0] = charlie;
object[] array4 = new Object[1];
array4 [0] = delta;

doc.write(array1, array2, array3, array4);
```

Or is object[] the method in which multiple parameters are passed, and you must literally create an array?

```
object[] params = new Object[4];
params[0] = alpha;
params[1] = bravo;
params[2] = charlie;
params[3] = delta;
doc.write(params);
```

Or is the array[] just a decoy, and really you pass:

```
doc.write(alpha, bravo, charlie, delta);
```

---

When i originally used this code, from a native Win32 app, the BSTR was placed inside a SAFEARRAY. In IDispatch based automation, everything is inside an array. In this case the late binding code:

```
doc.write(html);
```

was converted by the compiler into a SAFEARRAY, where the zero-th element contains a BSTR string (which is a length prefixed unicode string).

My problem becomes one of trying to construct a SAFEARRAY, converting a String into a BSTR, placing the BSTR into the zero-th element of the SAFEARRAY, and passing a variable that contains a SAFEARRAY to one that only accepts an object array (object[]).

**This is the real question:** how to create a BSTR SAFEARRAY?

---

> Microsoft.mshtml
>
> C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop
>   Assemblies\Microsoft.mshtml.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration for the write method on the [`IHTMLDocument2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface created by TLBIMP/VS.NET is incorrect.  It should be:

```
void Write([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)] object[] psarray);
```

You will have to define this interface in code and then use that.

Comment: Does that mean that i cannot use Microsoft's Microsoft.mshtml.dll primary interop assembly?

Comment: Perhaps you can, but I've never used this method, and looking at the IDL for the unmanaged interface, it would seem that the interop definition is incorrect.

Comment: How are you importing it, when i import from the COM tab "Microsoft HTML Object Library", which is "c:\Windows\System32\MSHTML.TLB", it's still wrong.

Comment: I'm not importing it, I recommended declaring the interface in code manually and using that.

Comment: It's a pretty large interface, is the solution you're describing to import all of it, and then change the one signature?

Comment: You could use reflector to get the interface from the assembly produced by TLBIMP, and then paste that into a code file into your project, and then use THAT definition (do not use the one in MSHTML).

Answer (score 1):

The params keyword indicates that you can supply multiple parameters in this place, and it will group automatically.  For example, if I had a function thus:

```
public int SumNumbers(params int[] value)
{
       //Logic.
}
```

then I could call it like this:

```
int myValue = SumNumbers(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

The array is constructed automagically.  So hypothetically, you could call

```
mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass doc;
...
doc.write('H','I',' ','M','O','M');
```

And it would work.  Not really practical though.  I suppose you've tried calling

```
doc.write(myString.ToCharArray());
```

?  I don't know anything about SAFEARRAYS, but its possible you might not have to know, either, depending on how the compiler helps/hinders here.

Comment: Did you mean to write "params int value[]" rather than "params int[] value"? Your example seems to indicate that it accepts a varialbe number of integers, and the target method receives them as an array. But "int[] value" would be more logical if the final guy receives as array of values.

Answer (score 1):

It works like a charm this way :

```
[Guid("332C4425-26CB-11D0-B483-00C04FD90119")]
[ComImport]
[TypeLibType((short)4160)]
[InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
internal interface IHTMLDocument2
{
    [DispId(1054)]
    void write([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string psArray); //modified 
    //void write([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_VARIANT)] object[] psarray); //instead of
```

Comment: Is it just a cut/paste snippet, or were you actually able to get away with declaring the interface with only one method?