# How to pass SAFEARRAY to COM object through IDispatch?

Tags: winapi, com, variant, safearray

i am trying to call a method of COM object, where one of the ***documented*** parameters is an *"array of bytes*". The actual declartion depends on the per-language documentation you're looking at:

- in **C#** language:

  ```
  byte[] TransformFinalBlock(
      byte[] inputBuffer,
      int inputOffset,
      int inputCount
  )
  ```
- in **C++** language;

  ```
  array<unsigned char>^ TransformFinalBlock(
      array<unsigned char>^ inputBuffer, 
      int inputOffset, 
      int inputCount
  )
  ```
- in **VB** language:

  ```
  Function TransformFinalBlock ( _
      inputBuffer As Byte(), _
      inputOffset As Integer, _
      inputCount As Integer _
  ) As Byte()
  ```
- in **F#** language:

  ```
  abstract TransformFinalBlock : 
          inputBuffer:byte[] * 
          inputOffset:int * 
          inputCount:int -> byte[]
  ```

The object i'm using can also be accessed using **COM**. The object provides an early binding interface, `ICryptoTransform`, which declares the method as using [**`SAFEARRAY`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221482(v=vs.85).aspx).

From the **type library**:

- using **IDL** syntax

  ```
  [
    odl,
    uuid(8ABAD867-F515-3CF6-BB62-5F0C88B3BB11),
    version(1.0),
    dual,
    oleautomation,
    custom(0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9, "System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform")    
  ]
  interface ICryptoTransform : IDispatch {
     ...
     [id(0x60020005)]
     HRESULT TransformFinalBlock(
                  [in] SAFEARRAY(unsigned char) inputBuffer, 
                  [in] long inputOffset, 
                  [in] long inputCount, 
                  [out, retval] SAFEARRAY(unsigned char)* pRetVal);
  };
  ```
- using **object Pascal** syntax:

  ```
  ICryptoTransform = interface(IDispatch)
       ['{8ABAD867-F515-3CF6-BB62-5F0C88B3BB11}']
       ...
       function TransformFinalBlock(inputBuffer: PSafeArray; inputOffset: Integer; inputCount: Integer): PSafeArray; safecall;
  end;
  ```

This means that when using *early-binding* you must pass the method a `SAFEARRAY`. The language i use has support for SafeArray APIs, can i can perform the call easily enough:

```
var
   inputBuffer: PSafeArray;
   xform: ICryptoTransform;
   ...
begin
   ...

   xform.TransformFinalBlock(inputBuffer, ...);
   ...
end;
```

Here's the same code in a java-like language:

```
PSafeArray inputBuffer;
ICryptoTransform xform;

...

xform.TransformFinalBlock(inputBuffer, ...);
```

And everything works *fine*; but that's not my question.

> **Note**: i'm trying drive home the point that this is a **language-agnostic** question, as **COM is a language agnostic technology**. But at some point we have to actually *use* a language that we will demonstrate code in. [Some people confuse a language with a technology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972829/how-to-call-use-net-rijndaelmanaged-from-native-com). If i knew Knuth's invented language, i would have used that.

### But what about late-binding `IDispatch`?

Now that we know we *can* pass a [`SAFEARRAY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221482(v=vs.85).aspx) to a COM object (when using ***early-binding***), i need to solve the problem of passing an array using ***late-binding***.

> **Note**: The question of how to pass a SAFEARRAY to a COM object through IDispatch is useful me to in circumstances besides `ICryptoTransform`.
>
> - [passing an array of `BSTR` to MSHTML control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489048/net-mshtml-how-to-pass-a-bstr-safearray)
> - [passing an array of byte to other COM objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972829/how-to-call-use-net-rijndaelmanaged-from-native-com)

Some languages provide automatic mechanisms to invoke methods through an `IDispatch` interface at run-time (i.e. *late-binding*). In fact `IDispatch` late binding was invented for VBScript:

```
Dim xform = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed");
Dim buffer;
o.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, 8);
```

And late-binding compiler auto-magic was added in .NET 4.0:

```
dynamic xform = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed", true));
xform.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, 8);
```

Late-binding compiler magic also existed in Delphi:

```
xform: OleVariant;
buffer: OleVariant;
xform.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, 8);
```

i *happen* to be using Dephi, and this call fails.

### But it's not really compiler magic

It's not really magic what VBScript, C# dynamic, and Delphi are doing. They're just calling [`IDispatch.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221479%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
IDispatch = interface(IUnknown)
   ['{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}']
   function Invoke(DispID: Integer; const IID: TGUID; LocaleID: Integer;
         Flags: Word; var Params; VarResult, ExcepInfo, ArgErr: Pointer): HResult; stdcall;
end;
```

The mess is setting up these parameters:

```
xform.Invoke(
      1610743820,      //DispID
      IID_NULL,        //riid (reserved for future use, must be IID_NULL)
      0,               //locale id (lcid)
      DISPATCH_METHOD, //flags
      dispParams,      //Pointer to a DISPPARAMS structure
      null,            //Pointer to the location where the result is to be stored, or NULL if the caller expects no result
      exceptInfo,      //Pointer to a structure that contains exception information
      null);           //This argument can be set to null.
```

The real trick is the `dispParams` structure, that contains the arguments.

### The argument will be an variant

The arguments that get passed through DISPPARAMS are all variants:

```
typedef struct tagDISPPARAMS {
  VARIANTARG *rgvarg;
  DISPID     *rgdispidNamedArgs;
  UINT       cArgs;
  UINT       cNamedArgs;
} DISPPARAMS;
```

So no matter what happens, my *"array of bytes"* is going to be a variant.

A [`VARIANT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908601.aspx), in Win32, is simply a union that contains:

- `VARTYPE vt`: The type of data in the union.
- the appropriate union member, e.g.:

  ```
  BYTE        bVal;
  IDispatch  *pdispVal;
  SAFEARRAY  *parray;
  BYTE       *pbVal;
  IDispatch  *ppdispVal;
  SAFEARRAY  *pparray;
  VARIANT    *pvarVal;
  PVOID       byref;
  CHAR        cVal;
  ```

Up to now i have been passing a variant of type:

```
vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1
```

MSDN documents what you must do when you want to use the **parray** union with `VT_ARRAY | *`:

> **Value**: `VT_ARRAY | <anything>`
>
> **Description**: An array of data type  was passed. VT_EMPTY and VT_NULL are invalid types to combine with VT_ARRAY. The pointer in **pbyrefVal** points to an array descriptor, which describes the dimensions, size, and in-memory location of the array.

What this means is that using the **`parray`** member:

```
    SAFEARRAY  *parray;
```

You need to set `parray` member to a pointer to a [`SAFEARRAY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221482%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure:

```
typedef struct tagSAFEARRAY {
  USHORT         cDims;
  USHORT         fFeatures;
  ULONG          cbElements;
  ULONG          cLocks;
  PVOID          pvData;
  SAFEARRAYBOUND rgsabound[1];
} SAFEARRAY, *LPSAFEARRAY;
```

In my case, my ***array of bytes*** is actually a `SAFEARRAY`, which is then being stored in a variant:

```
VARIANT *inputBuffer;
SAFEARRAY *safeArray;

//Setup our SAFEARRAY of data
safeArray.cDims = 1;
safeArray.fFeatures = FADF_HAVEVARTYPE;
safeArray.cbElements = 1;
safeArray.cbLocks = 0;
safeArray.pvData = pMyData;
safeArray.rgsabound[0].ElementCount = 1;
safeArray.rgsabound[0].LowBound = 0;

//Wrap the safearray in a variant
inputBuffer.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1; //$2011
vt.parray = safeArray;
```

> **Note**: Of course i'm not crazy enough to have created this safearray myself; i'm using the [`SafeArrayCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221234%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) api function. i'm just demonstrating that it's all knowable, and not magic.

### In other words i pass an array variant of bytes

In other words i *am* passing an array of bytes, wrapped in a variant, as all calls to:

```
dispatch.Invoke(...);
```

must be. Except that the *late-binding* call throws an error:

```
The parameter is incorrect.
```

So what am i possibly doing wrong?

How does one pass an **array of byte** to a **late-bound** `IDispatch` call?

### My Question

How to pass SAFEARRAY to COM object through IDispatch?

Comment: I am usually using `VARIANT` with `VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1` and it works fine.

Comment: @RomanR. Oh, that was my typo in the question. i typed `VT_BYTE` (i.e. `0x10`), but really i meant `VT_I1`) (i.e. `0x10`).

Comment: So what about `VT_UI1` == `0x11`?

Comment: @RomanR. i screwed it up again. The constant i had in my sample code (0x2011) was correct. i was then transcoding that into Delphi `varArray or varByte` into *C-style* `VT_ARRAY | VT_BYTE`. But `VT_BYTE` wasn't the right constant, so i changed it to `VT_I1`. At my glance of your code i thought that's what it was. ***Now*** i see i screwed it up ***again***, and `0x11` is `VT_UI1`. Which *is* what the code already uses (`0x2011`). Sorry.  For the record i've tried array of `VT_I1` and array of `VT_UI1`. My next step will be to step into the assembly code of `.Invoke(...)`

Comment: My point is that if your code is on both side of marhsaling layer, the caller and the callee, `VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1` variants are travelling through just fine. If they don't (error like `E_INVALIDARG` for no other reason) I would suppose the variant itself is broken, e.g. incorrectly initialized `SAFEARRAY`.

Comment: @RomanR. Granted i didn't initialize the `SafeArray` structure myself (i used a Windows API for that), i checked the members of the structure. The contents of the `SAFEARRAY` you can see towards the end of the question; and they look reasonable to me.

Comment: I see you are at loss, I made a simple project that works (see answer).

Answer (score 2):

This should give you some insight:

On the caller side, C# code:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
byte[] input = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
byte[] output = foo.Bar(input);
byte[] referenceOutput = new byte[] { 4, 3, 2, 1 };
Debug.Assert(Enumerable.SequenceEqual(output, referenceOutput));
```

The `Foo.Bar` IDL:

```
interface IFoo : IDispatch
{
    [id(1)] HRESULT Bar([in] VARIANT vInput, [out, retval] VARIANT* pvOutput);
};
```

And C++ (ATL) server implementation with safe arrays:

```
// IFoo
    STDMETHOD(Bar)(VARIANT vInput, VARIANT* pvOutput) throw()
    {
        _ATLTRY
        {
            ATLENSURE_THROW(vInput.vt == (VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1), E_INVALIDARG);
            CComSafeArray<BYTE> pInputArray(vInput.parray);
            ATLASSERT(pInputArray.GetDimensions() == 1);
            const ULONG nCount = pInputArray.GetCount();
            CComSafeArray<BYTE> pOutputArray;
            ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(pOutputArray.Create(nCount));
            for(ULONG nIndex = 0; nIndex < nCount; nIndex++)
                pOutputArray[(INT) nIndex] = pInputArray[(INT) ((nCount - 1) - nIndex)];
            ATLASSERT(pvOutput);
            VariantInit(pvOutput);
            CComVariant vOutput(pOutputArray.Detach());
            ATLVERIFY(SUCCEEDED(vOutput.Detach(pvOutput)));
        }
        _ATLCATCH(Exception)
        {
            return Exception;
        }
        return S_OK;
    }
```

Source: [Trac](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/ByteArrayVariant), [Subversion](http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/ByteArrayVariant/) - beware Visual Studio 2012.